# parse tag with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have this string:

```
   s='data-id="a1429883480588" class="privateMessage" @zaza
    data-id="a1429883480589" class="privateMessage" @zaza2
    data-id="a1429883480598" class="privateMessage" @zaza3'
```

My goal is to capture the what's between : data-id=" and " to have results:
[a1429883480588, a1429883480589, a1429883480598]

I tried with

```
var splitted = s.match(/data-id="(\w)+(?=")/g)
```

But this also captures data-id=" and "

Any idea on how to write this regex ?

**It must be done with JS since it is nodeJS function !**

Comment: Why regex? Using a document fragment would most likely be safer

Comment: Don't. Use DOM manipulation.

Comment: Don't parse HTML with RegEx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: IT IS inside NODEJS !

Comment: You can use Cheerio to parse the DOM in node.

Comment: I guess, but really need a regex instead of using a module...

Comment: You really don't want to use regex for this.

Comment: @yarek: while the comments to which you're responding may appear glib, and offered without relevance to your specific problem, they're right: parsing an irregular language with JavaScript's regular expression (or any other language's regex) is a minefield with more edge cases than you'll ever catch or plan for. It really is a fool's errand. Use whatever DOM parsing tools that are available for your environment, and save yourself the frustration.

Comment: I know that perfectly.. But I really need a regex for this very specific case.

Comment: You *really* don't. Find another solution.

Comment: A better solution would be to get those values you need passed to you from where ever the source is. If it's a script on a page, have that script parse the HTML before sending it.

Comment: I just edit the question and removed the HTML part so answers should not be obsessed with DOM parsing but a simple regex expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you're happy that the string will always be well formed and not mangled up. Here's one that'll do it:

```
var s = '<span data-id="a1429883480588" class="privateMessage">@zaza</span>&nbsp;';
s += '<span data-id="a1429883480589" class="privateMessage">@zaza2</span>&nbsp;';
s += '<span data-id="a1429883480598" class="privateMessage">@zaza3</span>';

s.match(/data-id="\w+"/g).map(function(attributeAndValue) {
    return attributeAndValue.split('"')[1];
})
```

The concerns raised above about using RegEx to parse HTML are valid but more for HTML in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cheerio equivalent, just for reference or whatever

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var markup = '<span data-id="a1429883480588" class="privateMessage">@zaza</span>&nbsp;<span data-id="a1429883480589" class="privateMessage">@zaza2</span>&nbsp;<span data-id="a1429883480598" class="privateMessage">@zaza3</span>';
var $ = cheerio.load('<div>'+markup+'</div>');
var ids = Array.prototype.map.call($('[data-id]'), function(e) {
    return $(e).attr('data-id');
});

console.log(ids);
// [ 'a1429883480588', 'a1429883480589', 'a1429883480598' ]
```